# Using formulas within nlapiSearchRecord columns

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

When using adhoc nlapiSearchRecord within scripts, such as:

```
        var filters = new Array();
        var columns = new Array();
                filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive', null, 'is', 'F' );
                filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('vendorcost', null, 'greaterthan', 0);
                filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', 'vendor', 'anyof', vendorid );
                columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid');
                columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid', 'vendor');
                columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorcode');
                columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('formulanumeric'); 
                    columns[3].setFormula('{vendorcost}');
                columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorpricecurrency');
                columns[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('isinactive');
                columns[6] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendor');
                columns[7] = new nlobjSearchColumn('averagecost');
                columns[8] = new nlobjSearchColumn('lastpurchaseprice');
                columns[9] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custitem_costrepl');
                var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, filters, columns );
```

How do I retrieve the value of the formula in column 3?

I've tried `searchresults.getValue(column[3]))` and `searchresults.getValue(3))` but both fail.

The reason for this, is some of our `vendorcost` values are 4 or 5 decimal places, but the most decimal precision the plain search returns is 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the fact that searchResults is an array

And there are multiple ways:

Option#1 //works always

```
searchresults[INDEX].getValue(searchresults[INDEX].getAllColumns()[3]);
```

Option#2 //works always - same as what you tried, but, you missed array

```
searchresults[i].getValue(columns[3]);
```

Option#3 //use only if you have one numeric formula

```
searchresults[INDEX].getValue('formulanumeric');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var filters = new Array();
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive', null, 'is', 'F');
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('vendorcost', null, 'greaterthan', 0);
filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', 'vendor', 'anyof', vendorid);

var columns = new Array();
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid');
columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid', 'vendor');
columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorcode');
columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('formulanumeric').setFormula('{vendorcost}'); // you can use formula inline
columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorpricecurrency');
columns[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('isinactive');
columns[6] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendor');
columns[7] = new nlobjSearchColumn('averagecost');
columns[8] = new nlobjSearchColumn('lastpurchaseprice');
columns[9] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custitem_costrepl');
var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, filters, columns);

for (var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++) {
    var vendorcost = searchresults[i].getValue(columns[3]);  // gives you the formula field value
}
```